# Getting numbers of hex number

Tags: java, hex

```
int n= 0x234;
```

This will actually store `564` in n, but what if I want to have access and operate with 2,3 and 4?

Comment: How do you want to operate on them?

Comment: Use bit shifts/bit masks... But what will you do with `f`?

Comment: Say, I want to add 2 hex numbers, but not add them as ints and print the result as hex.

Comment: Adding a number in hex or decimal will yield the same result.

0x123 + 0x345 = 0x468
==
291 + 837 = 1128

0x468 = 1128

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hex digits are very easy to get: to access the value of the digit `k`, counting from right, shift the value right by `4*k`, and mask with `& 0x0F`.

```
int n= 0x234;
int digit2 = (n >> 2*4) & 0x0F; // Gives you 2
int digit1 = (n >> 1*4) & 0x0F; // Gives you 3
int digit0 = (n >> 0*4) & 0x0F; // Gives you 4
```

Comment: Ah, one thing. How can I get the length of my number n? Say, I want to loop and get each of the digits but not knowing its length beforehand.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Start from the right side, grab the last digit, then shift the number right by four. Once the original number gets to zero, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bb.putInt(0x234);
for (byte b : bb.array()) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", b) + " "); //00 00 02 34
}
```